# Insert grid of images into about page

Tags: media

Im new to the forum  Hope you are all well?

I have a really simple thing I want to do with drupal but for the life of me I cant seem to get it right (I'm a beginner with drupal)

So I have an about page, and I add the body to the page. But what I want is to add images of members of the company the site is for above the body of text in the about page, like in a grid. So it would be the grid (say 3x3 image grid) then the body text at the bottom of the grid. How do I do this? I cant seem to find an answer anywhere and I'm pulling my hair out here.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are different pieces to this problem.

1. The grid with images.
   You can do that with Views. I'd say create a Views display of type "Block".
   E.g. if every member of the company is a node or a user with an image field, then you can use the view to show an image for each of them. There is a display plugin to show items in a grid.
2. Display this stuff on one page.
   One way to do that is with [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).
   Another way is to create a node type with a [Block reference](http://drupal.org/project/blockreference) field in addition to the body text field. You create the about page as a node of that type, and fill in the body text and reference the Views block you just created.
   Yet another way is to simply put the block into a theme region, and configure it to only show up on the "about" path.

Another way for all of this is to create a node type with a multiple-value image field. This is if you don't want every single member of the company to be a node or user entity by itself.

Then you can use a custom formatter, or just some CSS, or Display suite hook_ds_field_theme_functions_info(), to display the images in a grid.

Comment: You see there are many ways to do this. Which is the best depends on how you want your site architecture to be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the best and easiest way to achieve this is using a WYSIWYG editory like CKEDITOR, which is available for Drupal - https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor and yes, its free too.
For image, you can use IMCE as well
With this you can have much control as to how your page looks like and can change the layout of the page too.